# How can I use Django permissions without defining a content type or model?

Tags: django, django-permissions

I'd like to use a permissions based system to restrict certain actions within my Django application. These actions need not be related to a particular model (e.g. access to sections in the application, searching...), so I can't use the [stock permissions framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions) directly, because the [`Permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.models.Permission) model requires a reference to an installed content type.

I could write my own permission model but then I'd have to rewrite all the goodies included with the Django permissions, such as:

- The possibility to assign permissions to users and groups.
- The [`permission_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required).
- [`User.has_perm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) and related user methods.
- The [`perms` template variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id9).
- ...

I've checked some apps like [django-authority](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/) and [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian), but they seem to provide permissions even more coupled to the model system, by allowing per-object permissions.

Is there a way to reuse this framework without having defined any model (besides `User` and `Group`) for the project?

Comment: Django-guardian allows the object parameter to be optional: https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#assign-perm - see "Global permissions"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Django's `Permission` model [requires a `ContentType` instance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5b2/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L73).

I think one way around it is creating a dummy `ContentType` that isn't related to any model (the `app_label` and `model` fields can be set to any string value).

If you want it all clean and nice, you can create a `Permission` [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) that handles all the ugly details of the dummy `ContentType` and creates "modelless" permission instances. You can also add a custom manager that filters out all `Permission` instances related to real models.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll complete your answer with my implementation.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot approve as I don't have enough reputation to review your edit (it asks me for +2k). Other users are rejecting your edits, so I suggest you add it as another answer (you have my upvote!) Thanks again.

Comment: That's weird. It really is a completion for your answer, so it makes sense to make it an edit. Anyway, I put it in another answer.

Answer (score 234):

For those of you, who are still searching:

You can create an auxiliary model with no database table. That model can bring to your project any permission you need. There is no need to deal with ContentType or create Permission objects explicitly.

```
from django.db import models
        
class RightsSupport(models.Model):
            
    class Meta:
        
        managed = False  # No database table creation or deletion  \
                         # operations will be performed for this model. 
                
        default_permissions = () # disable "add", "change", "delete"
                                 # and "view" default permissions

        permissions = ( 
            ('customer_rights', 'Global customer rights'),  
            ('vendor_rights', 'Global vendor rights'), 
            ('any_rights', 'Global any rights'), 
        )
```

Right after `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` you can use these permissions like any other.

```
# Decorator

@permission_required('app.customer_rights')
def my_search_view(request):
    …

# Inside a view

def my_search_view(request):
    request.user.has_perm('app.customer_rights')

# In a template
# The currently logged-in user’s permissions are stored in the template variable {{ perms }}

{% if perms.app.customer_rights %}
    <p>You can do any customer stuff</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nothing changed after i ran manage.py migrate... I don't see any new permissions :(

Comment: Did you add your app into your project (INSTALLED_APPS)?

Comment: This answer is perfect. I also []ed default_permissions, raise NotImplementedError on the model's save(), and might consider making has_*_permission() return False if the unmanaged model is truly JUST for this permission.

Comment: Pure brilliance! Works with Django 1.11

Comment: It isn't displaying in django admin User permissions section. Any idea how to bring it there ?

Comment: Make sure to do makemigrations then migrate

Comment: I suggest adding in the Meta class the following: `default_permissions = ()`. This will prevent Django automatically creating the default add/change/delete/view permissions for this model, which are most likely unnecessary if you're using this approach.

Comment: FYI make sure that this is defined in a file called `models.py` of an app listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` or the model will not be picked up by migrations.

Comment: If `makemigrations` is not picking up your dummy model, even after you properly configured `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, remember to create empty `migrations` python package at app level!

Comment: A small gotcha with this approach is that [`dumpdata` still includes unmanaged tables, by design](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13816), so `./manage.py dumpdata` with no additional arguments will fail on the missing table.

Comment: 'makemigrations' did not work (see comment above for the reason). 'makemigrations <myapp>' worked.

Comment: thanks for sharing, it works! Although still looks hacky and not intuitive, as it still makes django add a new row to `django_content_type`  referring to a model that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Take care that you can't inherit the `default_permissions` attribute. If you want to build some kind of mixin, this won't work by design: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29386

Answer (score 56):

Following [Gonzalo's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13933002/486362), I used a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) to handle my "modelless" permissions with a dummy content type.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class GlobalPermissionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(GlobalPermissionManager, self).\
            get_query_set().filter(content_type__name='global_permission')


class GlobalPermission(Permission):
    """A global permission, not attached to a model"""

    objects = GlobalPermissionManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ct, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
            name="global_permission", app_label=self._meta.app_label
        )
        self.content_type = ct
        super(GlobalPermission, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it would be nice to also show an example on how to use this code.

Comment: where should that model permission live?

Comment: @MiratCanBayrak, I believe it suppose too live somewhere in your core app.

Comment: To create a GlobalPermission:
from app.models import GlobalPermission
gp = GlobalPermission.objects.create(codename='can_do_it', name='Can do it')

Once this is run you can add that permission to users/group like any other permission.

Comment: @MiratCanBayrak I'd rather put it at the end of app's models.py as it contains code which influence database.

Comment: @JulienGrenier The code breaks in Django 1.8: ```FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: app_label, id, logentry, model, permission```.

Comment: I got the same error as @maciek , and I'm on django 1.8.2, after I remove the `name` from the parameter, I got `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_permission.content_type_id`, I can't wrap my head around this, can @Chewie maybe update your implementation?

Comment: What's the purpose of filtering in `get_query_set`?

Comment: Warning: Newer versions of Django (at least 1.10) need to override the method "get_queryset" (note the lack of _ between the words "query" and "set).

Answer (score 11):

Fix for Chewie's answer in Django 1.8, which as been requested in a few comments.

It says in the release notes:

> The name field of django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType has been
> removed by a migration and replaced by a property. That means it’s not
> possible to query or filter a ContentType by this field any longer.

So it's the 'name' in reference in ContentType that the uses not in GlobalPermissions.

When I fix it I get the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class GlobalPermissionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(GlobalPermissionManager, self).\
            get_queryset().filter(content_type__model='global_permission')


class GlobalPermission(Permission):
    """A global permission, not attached to a model"""

    objects = GlobalPermissionManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "global_permission"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ct, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
            model=self._meta.verbose_name, app_label=self._meta.app_label,
        )
        self.content_type = ct
        super(GlobalPermission, self).save(*args)
```

The GlobalPermissionManager class is unchanged but included for completeness.

If using Django admin to create/edit these permissions, think of removing the content_type field to avoid confusion:

```py
class GlobalPermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "codename")
    exclude = ("content_type",)

admin.site.register(GlobalPermission, GlobalPermissionAdmin)
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix it for django 1.8 as in time of syncdb django asserts that the "name" field cannot be null.

Comment: It worked for me, but I'm not using migrations due to non-django legacy stuff still in my project. Are you upgrading from a previous django, because there isn't supposed to be a name field in 1.8

Answer (score 5):

This is alternative solution. First ask yourself: Why not create a Dummy-Model which really exists in DB but never ever gets used, except for holding permissions? That's not nice, but I think it is valid and straight forward solution.

```
from django.db import models

class Permissions(models.Model):

    can_search_blue_flower = 'my_app.can_search_blue_flower'

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ('can_search_blue_flower', 'Allowed to search for the blue flower'),
        ]
```

Above solution has the benefit, that you can use the variable `Permissions.can_search_blue_flower` in your source code instead of using the literal string "my_app.can_search_blue_flower". This means less typos and more autocomplete in IDE.

Comment: Does using `managed=False` not let you use `Permissions.can_search_blue_flower` for some reason?

Comment: @SamBobel yes, you could be right. I guess I just tried "abstract" the last time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `proxy model` for this with a dummy content type.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class CustomPermission(Permission):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ct, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
            model=self._meta.verbose_name, app_label=self._meta.app_label,
        )
        self.content_type = ct
        super(CustomPermission, self).save(*args)
```

Now you can create the permission with just `name` and `codename` of the permission from the `CustomPermission` model.

```
 CustomPermission.objects.create(name='Can do something', codename='can_do_something')
```

And you can query and display only the custom permissions in your templates like this.

```
 CustomPermission.objects.filter(content_type__model='custom permission')
```

Answer (score 2):

For my part, for any larger project, I find it useful to have a generic app that isn't really part of my project's data model *per se* - I typically call it "projectlibs". It's a simple django app where I put things like fixtures for imports, templatetags that can be reused for multiple apps, etc. Some of it is template stuff I find myself re-using often, so the added benefit of having that type of stuff in an app is that it's reusable for other projects.

So inside that `projectlibs/models.py`, you could:

You could create that "meta app", in essence, and assign the `content_type` to some dummy class:

```py
class UserRightsSupport(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()  # disable defaults add, delete, view, change perms
        permissions = (
            ("perm_name", "Verbose description"),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are bad for me except this:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Permission)

Permission.objects.create(
    content_type=content_type,
    name='...', codename='...',
)
```

which handles model-less permissions
without adding new models, but by adding new values.

Comment: That isn't model-less, it just uses the `Permission` content type (model).

Comment: @soxwithMonica `model-less` because a `Permission` model already exists so it is about adding new values, not models - that's why it satisfies `without defining a content type or model`.

Comment: I figured that, but it was better to state it explicitly anyway.

Comment: As simple as this approach looks, would have been the best answer but, adding permissions for your users on the `Permission` model is too risky. A little mistake can cause chaos

Answer (score 0):

I think that `User` model substitution do the trick (see Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Next on that model we can add `Meta` class with permissions and at the end we need to add our `User` model in `settings.py`.

Here is my example of `user.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = []  # disable "add", "change", "delete"
        # and "view" default permissions

        permissions = [
            ('customer_rights', 'Global customer rights'),
            ('vendor_rights', 'Global vendor rights'), 
            ('any_rights', 'Global any rights'),
        ]
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```