# Adding permissions to Django model without table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rbac

I'm working on some **Django Rest Framework** based project (quite expected API for some web-app). It has as traditional Django models, and some kind of model-like objects: they behave like Django models but don't store anything in DB. No tables, no content-types. When we ask them for objects, they goes to external API and forms resulting Queryset.

Now I need to build some role-based access system. To make the architecture clear and extensible, **I want to make groups and permissions managable** through the Django Admin interface. So, I guess, we need to put some permissions to DB and then we'll be able to add these permissions to user groups. After that, we'll check these permissions in `DRF.permissions` class. But since we have neither tables, nor content-types for these 'models', we can't add records to permissions table right now.

What is the right way to make this possible? Should I rebuild these 'models' through the metaclass with `proxy = True`? Or should I add a proxy layer above? Maybe I should add some dummy content-types by hand?

Comment: You should check this project https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules
It gives your powerful permission system without using database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Django permissions without defining a content type or model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932774/how-can-i-use-django-permissions-without-defining-a-content-type-or-model)